# Is there a null sequence that is in not in $\ell_p$ for any $p<\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Is 
$$\bigcup_{p<\infty}\ell_p=c_0 ?$$

At least one inclusion obvious: every $p$-summable sequence converges to zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider
$$
x(n)=\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}
$$
It is easy to check that $x\in c_0\setminus \left(\bigcup_{1\leq p<\infty}\ell_p\right)$. Indeed
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x(n) = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\log (n+1)}=0
$$
so $x\in c_0$. Now for fixed $p\in [1,+\infty)$ there exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $\log^p (n+1)<n$, so
$$
\Vert x\Vert_p=
\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\log^p (n+1)}\right)^{1/p}=
\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\log^p (n+1)}+
\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{\log^p (n+1)}\right)^{1/p}>
$$
$$
\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\log^p (n+1)}+
\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/p}=+\infty
$$
the last equality holds since the series
$$
\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}
$$
diverges.

Comment: Why is it the case that for a fixed $p \in [1, +\infty)$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$ we have $\log^p (n+1) < n$?

Comment: Because $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log^p(n+1)}{n}=0$$

Comment: Could you give me a clue as to how you'd prove this?

Comment: Using l'Hopitale rule prove that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n^{1/p}}=0$$

Comment: Man, I think there's a gap here. $\log(x+1)^5$ doesn't satisfy what you say. https://imgur.com/a/xX66hhp

Comment: @LucasGiraldi https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=Limit%5BLog%5Bx%2B1%5D%5E5%2Fx%2Cx-%3Einf%5D

Answer (score 4):

Prove: If $V$ is a separable Banach space, then $V$ cannot be written as a countable union of proper linear subspaces.

Because of inclusions among the $\ell_p$ spaces, your union is, in fact, equal to a countable union.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}=0\text{, but }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log(n+1))^p}=\infty\quad\forall p>0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{\ln n}$ converges to 0 but $\sum \frac{1}{\ln^p n} = \infty$ for any $p \geq 1$.