# Is it true that $\ell_1$ is closed subset of $\ell_p,\ \forall \ 1<p<+\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it hold that $\ell_1$ (or any $\ell_q$, with q<p) is closed (with respect to $\|\cdot\|_p$) subset of $\ell_p,\ \forall \ 1<p<+\infty$? I don't know, maybe I missed somethng. Firstly, I was wanting to show (by Baire's category theorem) that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{q<p} \ell_q\neq\ell_p,\ \forall\ 1<p<+\infty$. Thus, I prooved that every $\ell_q$ are meager subsets of $\ell_p,\forall\ q<p$ and now I am trying to proove that $\ell_q$ are closed (with respect to $\|\cdot\|_p$) in $\ell_p$, otherwise how can I apply Baire's Theorem? Are there any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: The standard unit vectors have dense span in $\ell_q$. If $\ell_1$ were closed, it   would be all of $\ell_q$.

Comment: Another way to phrase it (exactly the same thing as David) is that the $\ell_q$s can't be closed because they are dense in $\ell_p$ (by density of finitely supported sequences in every $\ell_p$) and distinct of $\ell_p$. However, it seems like [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111743/1104384) has answers that may help you, with both an explicit answer and a Baire appraoch.