# Existence of $k$ such that for $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=0$, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^k < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is it always possible to find a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for a sequence $a_n$, where
$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=0$, the sum
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^k < \infty $$
I suspect there is some pathological counterexample, but I have not yet found it. Any ideas?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111678/is-there-a-null-sequence-that-is-in-not-in-ell-p-for-any-p-infty

Comment: @Gary Amazing! Thanks a lot.